# Unable to Update Body of DataTable using an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DataTable that I am trying to load the data via and ajax call but the first line of data always says:

"No data available in table"
[image]

But under it the loaded ajax data is included. How do I remove the No data line and have the ajax data load into that spot?

Code Below:

```
<div class="box-body">
  <table id="changeTicketsTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Ticket Number</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Risk</th>
        <th>Primary CI</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Planned Start Date</th>
        <th>Actual Start Date</th>
        <th>Actual End Date</th>
        <th>Affected Partners</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Ticket Number</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Risk</th>
        <th>Primary CI</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Planned Start Date</th>
        <th>Actual Start Date</th>
        <th>Actual End Date</th>
        <th>Affected Partners</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Implementation of DataTable:

```
<script>
    getChangeTicketInformation();
    $('#changeTicketsTable').DataTable({
      "pageLength": 5,
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': true,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    });
  })
</script>
```

Javascript used to make Ajax call:

```
function getChangeTicketInformation(){
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "../../get_change_ticket_info",
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
         $('#changeTicketsTable').find('tbody').append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + item.number + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.short_description + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.risk + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.cmdb_ci_display_value + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.state + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.start_date + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.work_start + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.work_end + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + 'FILL IN' + '</td>'
            + '</tr>');
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Developer tools  in Chrome and type JUST the jquery (also below) into your page and see what happens.  then check the html and see if this is updated as expected - it might be there, but might be hidden.

But a better approach would actually be to use DataTable's built in ajax functionality:
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

```
$('#changeTicketsTable').find('tbody').append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + item.number + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.short_description + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.risk + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.cmdb_ci_display_value + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.state + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.start_date + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.work_start + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + item.work_end + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + 'FILL IN' + '</td>'
            + '</tr>');
        });
```

Comment: I would upvote this answer **if** solution, based on native DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) options was posted. Instead, I'm afraid, OP has accepted this answer for its code cooking up `<tbody>` HTML which is all wrong either - DataTables can do that itself, besides, table data is not affected with this method, thus, you can not use wast majority of DataTables API methods. So, had to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

With DataTable you can add new rows using the following API:

> [row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()): Add a new row to the table.

```js
function getChangeTicketInformation() {
        var data = [{number: 1, short_description: '1', risk: 1, cmdb_ci_display_value: 1, state: '1', start_date: '1', work_start: '1', work_end: '1'},
            {number: 2, short_description: '2', risk: 2, cmdb_ci_display_value: 2, state: '2', start_date: '2', work_start: '2', work_end: '2'},
            {number: 3, short_description: '3', risk: 3, cmdb_ci_display_value: 3, state: '3', start_date: '3', work_start: '3', work_end: '3'}];
        //$.ajax({
            //type: "GET",
            //url: "../../get_change_ticket_info",
            //success: function (data) {
                var dti = $('#changeTicketsTable').DataTable();
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    dti.row.add([
                        item.number,
                        item.short_description,
                        item.risk,
                        item.cmdb_ci_display_value,
                        item.state,
                        item.start_date,
                        item.work_start,
                        item.work_end,
                        'FILL IN'
                    ]).draw(false);
                });
            //}
            //});
    }

$('#changeTicketsTable').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 5,
    'paging': true,
    'lengthChange': true,
    'searching': false,
    'ordering': true,
    'info': true,
    'autoWidth': false
})
getChangeTicketInformation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div class="box-body">
    <table id="changeTicketsTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket Number</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Risk</th>
            <th>Primary CI</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Planned Start Date</th>
            <th>Actual Start Date</th>
            <th>Actual End Date</th>
            <th>Affected Partners</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket Number</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Risk</th>
            <th>Primary CI</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Planned Start Date</th>
            <th>Actual Start Date</th>
            <th>Actual End Date</th>
            <th>Affected Partners</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: There is even better solution - use DataTables embedded [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to pull the data.

Comment: You are right. There is also a jQuery plugin that can be considered. I added this answer only to evidence datatable is a plugin with own methods....

Answer (score 0):

I can give u a simple example for this.get array response from your ajax url and set them as following 
make `<tbody id='table_tbody_id'></tbody>`and

**Try this one**

```
function getChangeTicketInformation() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../../get_change_ticket_info",
    success: function (data) {

        for (let i in data) {
            let item = data[i];
            let number = item[0];
            let short_description = item[1];
            let risk = item[2];
            let cmdb_ci_display_value = item[3];
            let state = item[4];
            let start_date = item[5];
            let work_start = item[6];
            let work_end = item[7];

            let tableRow = "<tr>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + number + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + short_description + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + risk + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + cmdb_ci_display_value + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + state + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + start_date + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + work_start + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + work_end + "</td>\n" +
                "                        <td> " + 'FILL IN' + "</td>\n" +
                "                    </tr>";

            $('#table_tbody_id').append(tableRow);
        }

    }
});
}
```

And Call method

```
getChangeTicketInformation();
```

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because of 2 reasons. First, you shall **NOT** suggest to call jQuery `$.ajax()` method to populate DataTable, whereas embedded [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option exists which triggers AJAX-call where and when it is necessary. Second, it doesn't make sense to do DataTables job manually and cook up `<tbody>` html, not to mention it doesn't affect underpinning table data source and makes most of DataTables API useless.